# An effective algorithm for convolution of very many long signals

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I need to calculate the following linear convolution

$$ y[n] = h_1[n] \circledast h_2[n] \circledast h_3[n] \circledast \cdots \circledast h_{k-1}[n] \circledast h_k[n]$$

where $k$ exceeds $5000$ and the length of each $h_i[n]$ exceeds $100,000$.  I tried the method which is based on the circular convolution/DFT but it does not work because each $h_i[n]$ must be zero padded so DFTs then takes too much time and memory. Are there any other algorithm available?

Comment: what is the meaning of "$n$ exceeds 5000" when the length of $h_i[n]$ already exceeds 100,000?  why not just say $n$ exceeds 100,000?

Comment: I need to convolve 5000 sequences, each consistsis of 100,000 elements. I edited question

Comment: Are all $h_k[n]$ fixed or variable (like input signals)

Comment: They are all different but of the same length and sparse, i.e. less than 100 out of 100,000 are non-zeros

Comment: @zer0hedge: When implementing via the DFT, are you trying to do one really long zero-padded DFT of each sequence? It's not surprising that you would have problems with that, as the numbers you gave suggest you would need ~500-million-point DFTs. Instead, fast convolution techniques like [overlap-save](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) should be applicable to your problem; with this technique, the DFT size you use is only dependent on the lengths of the individual $h_i[n]$ signals, not the intermediate convolution results that grow in length after each step.

Comment: @JasonR Thanks, that's one option I'm considering at the moment. It is true that non-zero part of each $h_i[n]$ is shorter than 500M points

Comment: if you were to do the convolution in the most straight-forward naive way, how much computation would that take?  are all of the $h_i[n]$ the same length?

Comment: also, are your `h` real or complex? (doesn't change anything in principle, but might reduce computational time for some approaches)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson all $h_i[n]$ have the same length

Comment: @MarcusMüller $h_i[n]$ are real and sparse

Comment: @zer0hedge then doing this "naively" and linear is probably the fastest way...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Due to sparsity and the large number of multiplications involved, a leading and trailing parts of the 'running convolution' quickly become zeros. So I do a 'naive' convolution (i.e. apply $h_i[n]$ sequentially), but in addition I cut tails and heads of intermediate results and memorize how many zeros I cut from the head in order to add them in the end to the final result. It gives significant performance improvement, especially during the first steps. It currently takes less than 1 hour to calculate without parallelization.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, after the first two or three convolutions (like after $h_1[n] \circledast h_2[n] \circledast h_3[n]$) the intermediate result will be so long that i would consider it to be like a stream (indefinitely long).  then overlap-add or overlap-save fast convolution should take less time than the straight-forward "naive" way.  because you're convolving $h_i[n]$ against the result of $h_1[n] \circledast h_2[n] \circledast  ... \circledast h_{i-1}[n]$.  the latter is so long, i would call it a stream.

Comment: @zer0hedge, because $h_i[n]$ is sparse, it may be less expensive calculating the DFT $H_i[k]$ by the "naive" method than using the FFT.  but the intermediate result  $h_1[n] \circledast h_2[n] \circledast h_3[n] \circledast \cdots \circledast h_{i-1}[n]$ will get less and less sparse, so i think the "fast convolution" should use the FFT on the segments of that intermediate result as you are processing it.

Comment: Is it possible to talk a little bit more about the problem this calculation emerged in?

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm becoming a bit notorious with the whole "by using commonly available tools, how complex is your problem *really*?" business, but oh well:

I went ahead and simulated the "last" of your convolutions, i.e. I went ahead and picked up a FFT FIR (which is convolution by the overlap-save method Jason R [mentioned](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32445/an-effective-algorithm-for-convolution-of-very-many-long-signals#comment63008_32445)) by dumping 500 Million random samples through a filter of 100,000 taps:

[image: Flow graph]

So, this flow graph produces an average total of 42 MS/s, or 420 (500x100,000) convolutions per second. The complete program, which includes initial FFT of the taps, calculating of the taps and the random pool, loading of libraries and set up of all, takes about 12 seconds. So, yes, doing this exact operation 5000 times would exceed the average coffee break's duration, and take nearly 17h.

I tried timing the initial FFT of the tap vector (which the FFT filter blocks automatically), but I failed - it took much shorter than producing the taps vector itself. So I made a separate flow graph that just does 100,000-transforms of input data, and includes all the data generation/copying-overhead in my speed estimate. With that flow graph, my PC does 1900 FFTs per second, so it should take roughly half a millisecond to do a single one, or 2.5 s to do 5,000 of those.

Which also means that if you're smart, and just used the overlap-add algorithm as [contained in the FFT FIR block](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/v3.7.10/gr-filter/lib/fft_filter.cc) and hoped that performance scales roughly linear with length of the input vector you're transforming, then every convolution would take about $\frac{12}5\text{ ms}= 2.4\text{ ms}$ longer than the previous, giving us a rough estimate of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{5000} n\cdot 2.4\text{ ms}\approx 8\text{ h},\,25\text{ min}$.

Obviously, that leaves a bit of headroom for optimization. Now, Operlap-Add and Overlap-Save should actually scale exceptionally well to multi-core/distributed solutions. Also, doing a set of long FFTs also sounds like something that GPUs are great at.

Comment: A direct performance gain is achieved by dividing those 5000 or so cascade convolutions into parallel **pairs**. Such as $y[n] = h_1[n]*h_2[n]*h_3[n]*h_4[h]$ , brutally requires 3 serial convolutions. But if you first perform $y_1[n]=h_1[n]*h_2[n]$ and $y_2[n]=h_3[n]*h_3[n]$ and finally $y[n]=y_1[n]*y_2[n]$ . This requires 2 parallel and 2 serial convolutions. Similarly 512 such signals would require at most $\log_2(512) = 9$ serial steps instead of 511... of course assuming you can parallely convolve 256 pairs, which is only possible with GPU, a CPU would at best do 8 or 16 ?

Comment: @Fat32 pretty much what I've been thinking about; a "binary convolution tree". Problem really is that these kind of things vastly benefit from getting things from memory caches,so wildly jumping through "distant" payloads might offset the theoretical reduction in complexity at some point. Also,you're right,a CPU couldn't do so much in parallel (we're often also bound by mem bandwidth), and some of the operations in a single convolution already scale well on multiple CPU cores (FFTw has multi-threading, and point-wise multiplication scales excellently)->parallelize within conv, not across convs